# JQuery add message to a div if table is empty after search button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a search page that renders the results on the same page using a table below the search fields. I'd like to return a message if there are no search results.

I know how to do this by adding some text but the problem right now is my code detects for an empty table on page load (and displays the "no data" message before the search is performed by the user). I'd rather show the text only after the search button is clicked.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#account-grouping table tbody").each(function() {
if($.trim($(this).text()).length == 0)
{
var text = $.trim($(this).text());
text += "There was no data returned.";

$(".ac-message").text(text);
}
});
```

As you can see I check for an empty table and then pop a message into the div called `.ac-message`.  However, I'd really like to attach this all to the click event of the search button.

Comment: You can simply return the text you want using back end - if your query doesn't return any results - return "There was no data returned" to your ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your empty-checking code into a callback function that completes after your search is done.

```
var updateSearchResults = function(data) {
    if(data.length) { // depending on what format your data
                      // comes back in you may need a different test
        // Do something to populate your table
    } else {
        // Show your empty message
    }
};
$.get("/your/search/path", { "s": userSearch }, updateSearchResults);
```